# Search and edit records using userform

Tags: excel, vba

i'm relatively new to VBA and have muddled my way through to almost achieving the system i set out to produce.

I have now reached a brick wall and have been smashing my head against it for some time, help with my paradigm (tome only i'm sure) would be very much appreciated!!

So i am able to search for records and populate my user form from that, what i would like to do is update the found record through the same form when clicking the update button which is present on said user form.

```
Private Sub btsearch_Click()
Dim totrows As Long
totrows = Worksheets("Report").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
If Txtforename.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter guest name!!"
End If

For i = 2 To totrows
If Trim(Report.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(Txtforename.Text) And i = totrows Then
MsgBox "Guest Not Found"
End If
If Trim(Report.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(Txtforename.Text) Then
Txtforename.Text = Report.Cells(i, 1)
Txtsurename.Text = Report.Cells(i, 2)
Cboidtype.Text = Report.Cells(i, 3)
txtidnumber.Text = Report.Cells(i, 4)
Cboroomno.Text = Report.Cells(i, 5)
txtcheckin.Text = Report.Cells(i, 6)
txtcheckout.Text = Report.Cells(i, 7)
Cbopaymenttype.Text = Report.Cells(i, 9)
Txttotalpayment.Text = Report.Cells(i, 10)
cmbouser.Text = Report.Cells(i, 11)
Exit For
End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub btnupdate_Click()

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to update guest details?", vbYesNo + 
vbQuestion, "Update Record")
If answer = vbYes Then
Cells(currentrow, 1) = Txtforename.Text
Cells(currentrow, 2) = Txtsurename.Text
Cells(currentrow, 3) = Cboidtype.Text
Cells(currentrow, 4) = txtidnumber.Text
Cells(currentrow, 5) = Cboroomno.Text
Cells(currentrow, 6) = txtcheckin.Text
Cells(currentrow, 7) = txtcheckout.Text
Cells(currentrow, 9) = Cbopaymenttype.Text
Cells(currentrow, 10) = Txttotalpayment.Text
Cells(currentrow, 11) = cmbouser.Text
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you just need a global variable `currentrow` which you populate from `i` when you locate the row for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (untested).  The matched row is stored in a global variable so you can update it when you're finished editing

```
Dim CurrentRow As Range 'to store the matched row

Private Sub btsearch_Click()
    Dim totrows As Long, i As Long, fName

    fName = Trim(Txtforename.Text)
    If Len(fName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter guest name!!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    totrows = Report.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Set CurrentRow = Nothing 'clear any previous row

    For i = 2 To totrows
        If Trim(Report.Cells(i, 1)) = fName Then
            Set CurrentRow = Report.Rows(i)
            LoadRow CurrentRow '<< save the matched row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found!"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnupdate_Click()

    If MsgBox("Would you like to update guest details?", _
               vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update Record") = vbYes Then

        SaveRow CurrentRow

    End If
End Sub

'load a row of data into the userform
Sub LoadRow(rw As Range)
    With rw
        Txtforename.Text = .Cells(1).Value
        Txtsurename.Text = .Cells(2).Value
        Cboidtype.Text = .Cells(3).Value
        'etc etc
    End With
End Sub

'save the userform data back to the sheet
Sub SaveRow(rw As Range)
    With rw
        .Cells(1).Value = Txtforename.Text
        .Cells(2).Value = Txtsurename.Text
        .Cells(3).Value = Cboidtype.Text
        'etc etc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much tim, tried the code with no joy, am currently mobile so unable to give further details. Once I arrive home I will update. Thanks again

Comment: Hey tim my apologies with the slow reply, been bogged down with this one, the code above doesn't seem to achieve what i desired.  The search isn't effective and it submits data but only to the active worksheet and not to the same row as the data.  Thanks again for your attempted assitance!!

Comment: `CurrentRow` only gets populated by the search method, so I'm not sure how my code as posted could ever update the wrong sheet, unless `Report` is not the codename of your data sheet.  You use both `Worksheets("Report")` and just `Report` in your posted code, so I assumed they represented the same thing.

Comment: Finally figured it out thanks Tim, had to go a long way round but everything is working now. Thank you for your time and effort!!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is the result value of the `MsgBox`.  MsgBox always returns an integer, and `answer` is a variant.
Secondly I would declare `answer` as an integer.  Together it could become this :

```
. . .
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = Msgbox("Would you ... ecord")
    Debug.Print "' answer := " & answer ' display result in immediate-window
    MsgBox "' answer := " & answer ' or display the result with a msgbox
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Debug.Print "' then"
        ' while you are busy debugging, display this value too
        Debug.Print "' currentrow := " & currentrow
        . . . 
    Else
        Debug.Print "' else"
    End If
. . .
```